# How to find given key values (web.config) in Active Directory using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to Web API. I want to connect my PHP website with Web API in C# which will help to log in into website using Windows authentication. I'm specifiying a `key="name"` and `values="DavidR,JohnH"` in the `web.config` file. Only names provided in key values will be able to log into the system.

```
public bool Post(string user, string pass, string domain)
{
    DirectoryEntry objDirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, user, pass);

    try
    {
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(objDirEntry);
            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
            string[] name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["name"].Split(',');

            foreach (var author in name)
            {
                if (result == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else if(result == name)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="name" value="DavidR,JohnH"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: What is your problems?

Comment: Code is working fine without the key. The problem is i want to give access to only those names that I defined in the key. In my else if condition I got an error operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'SearchResult' and 'string[ ]'

Comment: Hi Mike! I've posted a problem related to my this post. Can you please have a look at it? Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
        public bool Post(string user, string pass, string domain)
    {
        DirectoryEntry objDirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, user, pass);
        try
        {
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(objDirEntry);
            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
            if (result == null)
                return false;
            string[] name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["name"].Split(',');
            foreach (var author in name)
            {
                if(author.ToLower() == user.ToLower())
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This code should works

You can use short code with `Linq` like this:

```
        public bool Post(string user, string pass, string domain)
    {
        DirectoryEntry objDirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, user, pass);
        try
        {
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(objDirEntry);
            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
            if (result == null)
                return false;
            string[] name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["name"].Split(',');

            if (name.Any(x => x.ToLower() == user.ToLower()))
                return true;
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```